# Typo3: doesn't work RTE editor for some be users

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, rte

I have 2 be users, admin and editor. Editor can edit some text, and same info. It worked well. But yesterday it broke. Now for editors rte fields looks like:[image]
For admin it's ok:[image]
I didn't anything changes for 2 weeks, only editor changed text and images.
How can I repair it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First guess if RTE is gone:
look for the **user settings**:
in the tab **Edit & Advanced functions** is a checkbox
`Enable Rich Text Editor (if available) 
[ ]`

Comment: thx, I enabled user settings and after that select checkbox Enable Rich Text Editor (if available). It works. But why it worked before without such actions?

Comment: either all usersettings were reset or the flag was cleared in another way